# difference in the usage of getch() and getchar() for clearing input buffer?

Tags: c, input, buffer, getchar, getch

CODE 1:-

```
char ch1, ch2;

printf("Input the first character:");

scanf("%c", &ch1); 

while(getchar()!='\n');

printf("Input the second character:");

ch2 = getchar();
```

In this case `while(getchar()!='\n');`, clears the effect of `enter-key` pressed for first input.

CODE 2:-

```
char ch1, ch2;

printf("Input the first character:");

scanf("%c", &ch1); 

while(getch()!='\n');

printf("Input the second character:");

ch2 = getchar();
```

In this case `while(getch()!='\n');`, do not clears the effect of `enter-key` pressed for first input. AND THE LOOP TURNS OUT TO BE INFINITE.

What is the difference in the functioning of `getch()` and `getchar()` this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `man getch`:

> Note that some keys may be the same  as  commonly  used  control  keys,
>          e.g., KEY_ENTER versus control/M, KEY_BACKSPACE versus control/H.  Some
>          curses implementations may differ according to whether they treat these
>          control  keys  specially (and ignore the terminfo), or use the terminfo
>          definitions.  Ncurses uses the terminfo definition.  If  it  says  that
>          KEY_ENTER is control/M, getch will return KEY_ENTER when you press con-
>          trol/M.

That means `getch()` returns `KEY_ENTER` instead of `'\n'` when it reads the enter key, and thus your `while` loop never terminates.

Answer (score 1):

`int getchar(void)` vs. `int getch(void);`

Both return an `int`.

Both may return values outside an 8-bit range, thus when saving the result, it should be saved in an `int`.

--

Difference between the 2:

`getchar()` is in the C spec.  `getch();` is not.

The return value from `getchar()` will display on the screen.  From `getch()` will not.

`getchar()` will go into an infinite `while()` loop should the EOF condition occur.  Better to use:

```
int c; 
while((c = getchar()) !='\n' && c != EOF);
```

`getch()` returns `ERR` on error or timeout.  There is some variation of the functionality on various systems - it is not specified in C.  Some allow an option to return immediately if there is no key in the queue.

When pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>, `getchar()` returns `'\n'`.
`getch()` returns the keycode.  which may match `'\n'`, `'\r'` or others.
This is OP's immediate problem.  @Ingo Leonhardt

Comment: both methods are not going into infinite loop

Comment: @kevin gomes `getchar()` will go into an infinite loop should the End-of-file condition occur. You did not experienced it because you did not terminate stdin. Different terminals accomplish that, some with Ctrl-D or Ctrl-Z or others. EOF is different than Enter

Answer (score 1):

[`getch()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getch) from `curses.h` is:

> get[ting]... characters from curses terminal keyboard

[`getchar()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getchar) from `stdio.h` is:

> read[ing] the next character from [stdin] and return[ing] it as an unsigned char cast to an int, or EOF on end of file or error.

So, your first example is reading the newline character (`'\n'`) left on `stdin` from the `scanf()` call, everything works.

Your second example, you're not using or linking to `curses` and so in no-delay mode, if no input is waiting, the value `ERR` is returned from `getch()`. `ERR` is `-1`, `'\n'` is `10`. They don't match so you go into an infinite loop waiting for `-1==10`